# StateChange for the RadioButtons inside the EditorFor Not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, editorfor

My Main model class

```
public class MainModel 
{

        public ProblemType? problemType { get; set; }


        public SubProblemType? subProblem { get; set; }
}
```

Enum's

```
public enum ProblemType
    {
        ProblemA =1,
        ProblemB =2
    } 

public enum SubProblemType
    {
        SubProblemTypeA =1,
        SubProblemType =2
    }
```

I also created my custom *editortemplate(EditorTemplate/ProblemType.cshtml)* for the both the enum

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x, "ProblemA")
@if (Model == ProblemType.ProblemA)
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x, (int)ProblemType.ProblemA, new { @checked = "checked" });
}
else
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x, (int)ProblemType.ProblemA);
}

@Html.LabelFor(x => x, "ProblemB")
@if (Model == ProblemType.ProblemB)
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x, (int)ProblemType.ProblemB, new { @checked = "checked" });
}
else
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x, (int)ProblemType.ProblemB);
}
```

The SubProblemType *EditorTemplate/SubProblemType.cshtml* is also same as the above view

Now in my main view I've trying to do some validation(client side) if the user choose the **ProblemA** Radio box, then only I've to show the subproblemType Radio Boxes.

So far I tried like below in my **mainView**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#problemType").on("change", StateChange(function () {
            if ($("#chkYes").is(":checked")) {
                $("#subProblem").show();
            } else {
                $("#subProblem").hide();
            }
        }));
    });

</script>


@Html.EditorFor(x => x.problemType, new { @onchange = "StateChange();" })

@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.subProblem)
```

But it's not working, I'm not getting triggered for change event when I choose the ProblemType Radio button in the js

Comment: What means: not working? Any error? Blank screen?

Comment: @VillageTech I've updated the question, There is no error, the js code is not getting triggered for any change event from the radio button